# How to wait for callback to finish before continuing the loop?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to add `restMedia` to `restaurantMediaList` in `onResponse` within a for loop. However, when the loop is finished, `restaurantMediaList` is null. How can I fix this in such a way that it waits for `onResponse` to be finished first before proceeding with the next iteration?

```
public void getImages(List<Restaurant> restaurantList, OnImageReceivedCallback callback){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        WordpressAPICall wordpressAPICall = retrofit.create(WordpressAPICall.class);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < restaurantList.size(); i++){
            String featuredMediaURL = restaurantList.get(i).get_links().getFeaturedMedia().get(0).getHref();
            featuredMediaURL.substring(featuredMediaURL.indexOf("v2")+1);
            Call<RestaurantMedia> restMediaCall = wordpressAPICall.getImage(featuredMediaURL);

            restMediaCall.enqueue(new Callback<RestaurantMedia>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RestaurantMedia> call, Response<RestaurantMedia> response) {
                    RestaurantMedia restMedia = response.body();
                    restaurantMediaList.add(restMedia);
                    //callback.onRestaurantListReceived(restaurantModels, restMedia);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RestaurantMedia> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Fail to get media", t.toString());
                }
            });
        }
        
        callback.onImageReceived(restaurantMediaList);
        
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling a rest API inside Loop . This is very bad practice. you should not do it . Instead create an API  which takes an array as an input .

Comment: I don't understand the down vote since it's a legit question if `getImages` is already called on a background thread and no batch API is available and it must wait for all of the images to arrive.

Comment: Try Retrofit's `execute()` method instead of `enqueue()`. Understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous requests/methods. In your code `execute()` (which is synchronous method) method better suited. But you need to handle it in a separate thread, not on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there are `restaurantList.size()` different threads (each fires a network request) and the only choice you have is to use some lock.

If there is an API that fetches all of the images together please use it and use my 1st code to wait for result.

I also recommend using timeout because if, for some reason, `onResponse` AND `onFailure` will not be called, your calling thread will sleep forever. Tweak the timeout as you see fit.

Waiting for each thread to finish separately is extremely time consuming so I'd recommend to let them go asynchronous and continue when all of them are done.

I'll show you both options.

Wait for each one to wait separately:

```
CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
restMediaCall.enqueue(new Callback<RestaurantMedia>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RestaurantMedia> call, Response<RestaurantMedia> response) {
          // Do your thing
          countDownLatch.countDown();
     }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RestaurantMedia> call, Throwable t) {
          // Do your thing
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
});
countDownLatch.await(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // join thread with timeout of second
```

Waiting for all threads together:

```
public void getImages(List<Restaurant> restaurantList, OnImageReceivedCallback callback){
    // Do your thing
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(restaurantList.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < restaurantList.size(); i++){
        // Do your thing
        restMediaCall.enqueue(new Callback<RestaurantMedia>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RestaurantMedia> call, Response<RestaurantMedia> response) {
              // Do your thing
              countDownLatch.countDown();
             }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RestaurantMedia> call, Throwable t) {
                 // Do your thing
                 countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });
    }
    countDownLatch.await(1L *  restaurantList.size(), TimeUnit.SECONDS); // join thread with timeout of second for each item
}
```